# Azure DevOps release pipeline, production stage permissions prevent changes to the entire pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration

We have an Azure DevOps release pipeline with stages representing deployment targets. The final stage (Production) is secured by preventing all but Release Administrators from Editing, Deleting or Managing Approvers for that stage only. They have Edit permissions on all other stages. This is done by selecting the production stage, clicking the (...) menu, security, switching off inheritance and adjusting the permissions as described.

Now, when making any change to the release pipeline (including adding a new stage, editing an 'unprotected' stage, adding a variable, updating an existing variable) anyone other than Release Administrators get an error:

> VS402904: Access denied: User XXX does not have edit release stage
>   permission. Contact your release manager. Stage name: Production

Surely this can't be as intended, securing one stage essentially locks out all changes to the entire release pipeline? Is there an alternative to restrict modification of a single stage while allowing others to continue to make changes to other stages and variables?

Answer (score 0):

Following your security setup steps, I switched off inheritance in the Production stage and set the permissions of the Contributors group to `Deny`. On my side, everything works well. In addition to not being able to edit the Production stage, members in the Contributors group can normally edit other stages in the pipeline, including adding stages and updating the variables.

[image]
[image]

Comment: If you include a variable scoped to Production do you see the behaviour described?

Comment: Users whose permissions are restricted by the Production stage cannot select the [Production scope](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eKeOW.png) when setting the variable and cannot [modify the variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NrPss.png) of the Production scope.

Comment: I have cloned one of the affected pipelines, set the security accordingly and the clone is working as expected, the original remains defective. I'd rather not have to clone all of our release pipelines to resolve this

Comment: You can check whether the changes of the Production stage is included when saving the release pipeline. As you  see, under normal circumstances there will be no such problem.